# ImportError: Undefined Symbol when importing python module 'pyfftw'

Tags: python, importerror, apt-get, armv7, pyfftw

I want to use pyfftw module and I install it using `sudo apt-get install python-fftw`. The FFTW module is already installed. However, when I try to `import pyfftw` this error happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyfftw/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .pyfftw import (
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyfftw/pyfftw.arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: fftwl_plan_with_nthreads
```

Anyone knows how to troubleshoot this? For additional information, my system architecture is armv7l (I am running the program in odroid), my OS is Ubuntu and I use python 2.7.12.

Thank you.

Comment: First google result for this error message: https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/issues/112

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/issues/203) might be relevant to you. I think your problem has probably been solved, but it might require you to pull in various branches until it's all merged properly.

Comment: @BaileyParker I tried that one but to no avail..

Comment: @HenryGomersall this works! Thank you for saving my life :)